# addTextChangedListener MoneyWatcher Only Working on Second List Entrance

Tags: java, android, list, dynamic

When I enter text into the "edit" EditText field in the app, it doesn't format as per the **MoneyTextWatcher**, however the second entry I make *does* format correctly. Any ideas on what's going on?

I was thinking about rewriting this so that I could use **private variables**, but my app crashed every time I tried that.

```
public class addBills extends ListActivity {
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_add_bills);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
            edit.addTextChangedListener(new MoneyTextWatcher(edit));
            EditText billName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.billName);
            list.add(billName.getText().toString() + " " + edit.getText().toString());
            edit.setText("");
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    /** Setting the event listener for the add button */
    btn.setOnClickListener(listener);

    /** Setting the adapter to the ListView */
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
public class MoneyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private final WeakReference<EditText> editTextWeakReference;

    public MoneyTextWatcher(EditText editText) {
        editTextWeakReference = new WeakReference<EditText>(editText);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        EditText editText = editTextWeakReference.get();
        if (editText == null) return;
        String s = editable.toString();
        if (s.isEmpty()) return;
        editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        String cleanString = s.replaceAll("[$,.]", "");
        BigDecimal parsed = new BigDecimal(cleanString).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR).divide(new BigDecimal(100), BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR);
        String formatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(parsed);
        editText.setText(formatted);
        editText.setSelection(formatted.length());
        editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove these two lines from `onCLick`

```
 EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
 edit.addTextChangedListener(new MoneyTextWatcher(edit));
```

And place these inside `onCreate` method but outside `onClick`

Comment: This was my initial thought, however, when I do this, the app crashed after I click btn.